# Setting Parent Node Variable in SimpleXML and XPath

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I am working with PHP and SimpleXML/XPath, and I'm just wondering how to set a certain parent (with a certain attribute value) equal to a variable, which I could use in a 'foreach'?

I'm currently getting this error:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion
```

and this output

```
Array
```

Thanks for any leads.

Here is the php code:

```
<?php
$url = "test_b.xml";


$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$xml_report_abbrev_b = $xml->xpath('//poster[@name="U-Verify"]')[0];

if($xml_report_abbrev_b){
    foreach($xml_report_abbrev_b as $node_a) {
        echo '<h1>'.$node_a->xpath('/full_image/@url').'</h1>';
    }
} else {
    echo 'XPath query failed';  
}

?>
```

Here's the xml:

```
<data>
  <poster name="U-Verify" id="uverify">
    <full_image url="u-verify.jpg"/>
    <full_other url=""/>
  </poster>
  <poster name="Minimum" id="min">
    <full_image url="min.jpg"/>
    <full_other url="spa_min.jpg"/>
  </poster>
</data>
```

Comment: Your xpath should be '//poster[@name="U-Verify"]/*' and you should not refer to the first element ( [0] ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SimpleXML's element access and attribute access directly instead of using the XPath query will make the code simpler and perform better.
Your code could be reduced to...

```
$xml_report_abbrev_b = $xml->xpath('//poster[@name="U-Verify"]');

if($xml_report_abbrev_b){
    echo '<h1>'.$xml_report_abbrev_b[0]->full_image['url'].'</h1>';
} else {
    echo 'XPath query failed';
}
```

Note the way the `echo` line says - with the `<poster>` element you found from the XPath expression, use the `<full_image>` element and fetch the `url` attribute.

I also moved the `[0]` into the `if` because if the XPath didn't find a value, this produced an error as there isn't any data to get a value from.

This outputs...

```
<h1>u-verify.jpg</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks - and to take this a step further, once I have this variable, how would I then get an attribute at its level?  For example, there are 2 attributes in the poster node, 'name' and 'id.'  How would I then get the 'id' after getting the level variable?

Comment: To get the id attribute - `$xml_report_abbrev_b[0]['id']`, basically `$xml_report_abbrev_b[0]` is the `<poster...` element, so everything you reference is relative to that.